# Parallel process with MATLAB(LINUX)

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, matlab-guide, matlabpool

Currently i am executing single file in matlab having infinite while loop.

```
loadconfig
while true
   command = meexcel.getGetParams();    
    refkey = command.get('refkey');
    try 
        if isempty(refkey) == false
            str='';
        document=command.get('documentid');

        documentlanguage=command.get('documentlanguage');
        if isempty(document) == false               
            s=loadSpace(filename,documentlanguage);
        end
        opt.Compact=1;          
        [temp1 temp2] = getPar;         
        jsondata=savejson('',temp1,opt);
        m = java.util.HashMap;           
        m.put('results', jsondata);
        meexcel.setGetParams(m,refkey);
    end 
catch err
    m = java.util.HashMap;
    m.put('results','{msg: Error during calculating}');
    m.put('refkey',refkey); 
    meexcel.setGetParams(m,refkey);
    disp(getReport(err));                                               
end

%plotSemantic function
command = meexcel.getPlotSemanticDistance();    
word = command.get('word'); 
try 
    if isempty(word) == false
        str='';
        refkey = command.get('refkey');
        documentlanguage=command.get('documentlanguage');
        if isempty(documentlanguage) == false               
            s=loadSpace(filename,documentlanguage);
        end

        [h out]=plotSemanticDistance(s,word);
        saveas(h,strcat(download_plot_dir,refkey,'.png'))
        result = strcat(download_plot_url,refkey,'.png');               
        m = java.util.HashMap;           
        m.put('results', result);
        meexcel.setPlotSemanticDistance(m,refkey);
    end 
catch err
    m = java.util.HashMap;
    m.put('results','Error during calculating');
    m.put('refkey',refkey); 
    meexcel.setPlotSemanticDistance(m,refkey);
    disp(getReport(err));

    end
end
```

How can i handle parallel execution of this file? the function like meexcel.getGetParams() will retrive data when it available. This file is having inifite loop.

Comment: You could use the `batch` command from the parallel computing toolbox. Is this toolbox available?

Comment: Thanks Daniel, but as newbie i dont know MATLAB well, i just want to do parallel process. Is there anyway to do this. batch command is available but dont know how to use!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to utilise parallel processing in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056831/how-to-utilise-parallel-processing-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using [`parfeval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfeval.html) from the [Parallel Computing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/parallel-computing/). Something like this:

```
queue = rand(1, 10); % simulated data
futures = [];
while ~isempty(queue)
   % Consume item from queue
   item = queue(end);
   queue(end) = [];
   futures = [futures; parfeval(@sqrt, 1, item)];
end
% Block until all futures are complete and fetch
% the results
fetchOutputs(futures);
```