# find common values of all rows of a matrix

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

I have a random generated matrix

```
A =[ 0.7015 -1.577  -1.333  0.022   -0.5    -2.00   -0.034 -0.714
     -2.05   -0.5   1.12    -0.26   -0.97   0.96    -0.79   1.35
     -0.353  0.28   -0.5       -1.75    -1.15   0.52    1.018   -0.22
     -0.8   0.033   -0.29   -0.28   -0.5    -0.02   -0.13   -0.58 ]
```

I want to find the common values of all rows.Each row has no duplicated elements. Can anyone give me a help?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What would the output be?

Comment: @Luis Mendo， the output would be -0.5. only -0.5 shows up in every row.

Comment: Start with a list containing the first row. Iterate through the rows removing the elements in the list that are not in the current row?

Comment: @Tonio, any better way? since my own matrix is 10* 5000, if do iteration, that would be very ugly!

Comment: @Angelababy I really doubt it. I guess you could use parallel processing to speed this up. Also adding a stop when the list is empty...

Comment: @Tonio, can you write a sample code for parallel processing ?I do not get you.

Comment: @Angelababy The main idea is to split your matrix and have workers perform the algorithm on the sub matrices and finally join all the workers' results (in this case the intersection). I'm not really a matlab expert, there might be other ways. At any rate this page provides different ways to do parallel processing in matlab: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056831/how-to-utilise-parallel-processing-in-matlab (disclaimer: I personally didn't do it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a vector of unique values with [`unique`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html), and then compare each element of `A` with each unique value using [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
u = unique(A);
m = squeeze(all(any(bsxfun(@eq, A, permute(u, [2 3 1])),2),1));
result = u(m);
```

This should be fast, but may be memory-hungry, as it generates a 3D array of size *m*x*n*x*p*, where `A` is *m*x*n* and *p* is the number of unique values of `A`. It works even if **a row can contains duplicated elements**.

---

Exploiting the fact that **each row has no duplicated elements**, you can use a possibly more memory-eficient approach with [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
[u, ~, w] = unique(A);
m = accumarray(w,1)==size(A,1);
result = u(m);
```

Comment: The error is :Error using bsxfun
Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must
match each other

Comment: can  you specify what "2" , "3", "1" represent? The example matrix A is 4*8, that I post in the question.

Comment: It works with your `A`. Those `[2 3 1]` are dimensions, so they shouldn't be changed evven if the size of `A` changes

Comment: it does not work with my A. This is the error I get:Error using bsxfun Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must match each other

Comment: Yes it does. Do `clear all`. Then paste `A` _as is_ in your question. Then my code also _as is_

Comment: No, It really does not work in my side. Please see the error: Error using bsxfun
Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must
match each other.

Comment: Yes it works. Are you doing _exactly_ as I say? Matlab version?

Comment: The first part of the code does not work. The second code part works

Comment: The second code part: [u, ~, w] = unique(A);
m = accumarray(w,1)==size(A,1);
result = u(m);  This part code works

Comment: But for the first part:u = unique(A);
m = squeeze(all(any(bsxfun(@eq, A, permute(u, [2 3 1])),2),1));
result = u(m); It does not work. my Matlab version is 2014a

Comment: Well, it works for me. You must be doing something different. Paste this and tell me: `clear all, A = eye(5); u = unique(A); m = squeeze(all(any(bsxfun(@eq, A, permute(u, [2 3 1])),2),1)); result = u(m)`

Comment: I paste the code exactly you gave it to me. This is the error: Error using bsxfun
Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must
match each other.  Same as the errors above

Comment: Weird. It works for me, both in R2010b and in R2014b. What's your Matlab version?

Comment: My Matlab version is R2014a

Comment: @Angelababy @LuisMendo What if the assumption `each row has no duplicated elements` is false? I mean, your matrix is generated `at random`, so how can you tell?

Comment: @Tonio "At random" doesn't necessarily mean there may be repeated values. For example, the values from each row could be sampled without repetition (via `randsample`) from a set of unique values. Anyway, if there may be repeated values, the first part of the answer works

Comment: @LuisMendo Oh, but it does. `at random` without context means just that. It is not `really` random if it follows a rule. Anyway, I'm just pointing out that you need to be aware of this if you use this method. If it suits your purposes that's perfect.