# how to find common values of rows of a matrix in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, slice

I have a tensor like this:

```
tf_a2 = tf.constant([[1, 2,  5 ],
                     [1, 4,  6 ],
                     [0, 10, 10],
                     [2, 4,  6 ],
                     [2, 4,  10]])
```

I would like to find whole indices in this matrice which are repeated more than `n` time.

For example: `1` being repeated `two times`. `2` being repeated `three times`. `5` being repeated `one time`. Repetition between rows is considered. Also, I want to skip the number `10` totally(10 is constant).

here `n=2`, So the result looks like: because `2 and 4` being repeated more than `two times`.

```
                    [[0, 2,  0 ],
                     [0, 4,  0 ],
                     [0, 0,  0 ],
                     [2, 4,  0 ],
                     [2, 4,  0 ]]
```

I found an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29783598/find-common-values-of-all-rows-of-a-matrix) but the explanations are for Matlab code.

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can use [`tf.unique_with_counts`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/unique_with_counts) to finds unique elements in a 1-D tensor.

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf_a2 = tf.constant([[1, 2,  5 ],
                     [1, 4,  6 ],
                     [0, 10, 10],
                     [2, 4,  6 ],
                     [2, 4,  10]])
n = 2
constant = 10

y, idx, count = tf.unique_with_counts(tf.reshape(tf_a2,[-1,]))
# y = [ 1  2  5  4  6  0 10]
# idx = [0 1 2 0 3 4 5 6 6 1 3 4 1 3 6]
# count = [2 3 1 3 2 1 3]
```

Then you can map repetition times to original tensor.

```
count_mask = tf.reshape(tf.gather(count,idx),tf_a2.shape)
# [[2 3 1]
#  [2 3 2]
#  [1 3 3]
#  [3 3 2]
#  [3 3 3]]
```

Finally you can skip the number `10` and get the result you expect by `tf.where`.

```
# skip constant and filter n time
result = tf.where(tf.logical_and(tf.greater(count_mask,n),
                                 tf.not_equal(tf_a2,constant)),
                  tf_a2,
                  tf.zeros_like(tf_a2))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(result))

# [[0 2 0]
#  [0 4 0]
#  [0 0 0]
#  [2 4 0]
#  [2 4 0]]
```