# Adding Parts of Matricies Slower than Whole

Tags: matlab

I have a simple code where I have a large 2-D matrix that I want to condense to be half the size in each dimension. A is the desired output (a 500 x 500) matrix, and it takes 0.004 seconds. However, B takes less time and it is a (1000 x 1000) matrix. My understanding is that it takes more time to create the temporary matrixes to compute A then it does to actually compute A; the solution is therefore the use of for loops, such that the 4 large (500 x 500) matrices dont actually have to be explicitly created. However, when it did it in the script (C), in a seperate function (C2) or in a compiled MEX file (C3), the compute time is still larger. (Even more puzzling is that compiling the code is slower than JIT for-loops in Matlab). 
Anyone have any idea what is going on?
TIA

```
    clc
clear all
N = 1e3;
X = rand(N);
i=1:2:N-1;
j=1:2:N-1;
tic
A = (X(j,i) + X(j,i+1) + X(j+1,i) + X(j+1,i+1))/4;
toc
%% Elapsed time is 0.003942 seconds.
tic
B = (X + X + X + X)/4;
toc
%% Elapsed time is 0.001632 seconds.
tic
I=1:2:N-1;
J=1:2:N-1;
C = zeros(N/2);
for i=1:length(I)
    for j=1:length(J)
        C(j,i) = (X(J(j),I(i))+X(J(j)+1,I(i))+X(J(j),I(i)+1)+X(J(j)+1,I(i)+1))/4;
    end
end
toc
%% Elapsed time is 0.012286 seconds.
tic
C2 = MyRestrict(X);
toc
%% Elapsed time is 0.010636 seconds.
tic
C3 = MyRestrict_mex(X);
toc
%% Elapsed time is 0.068403 seconds.
```

Comment: Don't know what you did in `MyRestrict` or `MyRestrict_mex`, so we can't comment on those. Either include the code (see [mre]) or leave that part of the question out.

Comment: Also, times are way too small for `tic`/`toc` to measure correctly. If you run your code repeatedly, you'll see timings fluctuate a lot. Use `timeit` to measure your code. And don't use `clear all`, it clears loaded functions from memory, making subsequent code slower than necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have not consider paralell processing nor how multithreads works.
[How to utilise parallel processing in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056831/how-to-utilise-parallel-processing-in-matlab)
https://es.mathworks.com/discovery/matlab-multicore.html
There are a lot of things you will have to understand about those 2 concepts, but basically:
Using a struture `for` makes Matlab work in an specific order, until an iteration has not finished, the next one cannot start.
Meanwhile if you use the code for A or B is way more efficient since you are not making matlab follow an exclusive order and you can take advantages of intrinsic multithreads inside Matlab(multiple tasks can be done at the same time). Example:

```
C(j,i) = (X(J(j),I(i))+X(J(j)+1,I(i))+X(J(j),I(i)+1)+X(J(j)+1,I(i)+1))/4;
```

C(1,1) is non dependant of any other C(j,i) so there is no need to wait for that iteration to finish to start thinking about the result of C(1,2).So, multithreading is useful here, each thread can do each mathematical operation like they are already doing in A and B.

Comment: I have thought of this, and I have tried disabling multithreading, but it didnt seem to make a difference at all, which is also surprising in its own right. I get similar results for methodA regardless if i set maxNumCompThreads(16) or maxNumCompThreads(1)

Answer (score 0):

I see much less difference than you do. `B` is a totally different result than `A` or `C`, so I'll ignore that part. `C2` and `C3` I cannot say anything about because there's no code for them, I don't know what those do.

With `N=1e3` I get 2.0ms for `A` and 3.3ms for `C`. The array is small enough that making four intermediate copies is not a big thing. The overhead of the loop, though small, is noticeable (MATLAB 15 years ago would have seen the loop being 100 times slower!). Note also that, as [Marta G. suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60821186/7328782), the summation for `A` is parallelized, MATLAB is able to use SIMD instructions and/or multiple cores to perform these additions. This speedup partly compensates for the cost of making data copies.

With `N=1e4` I get 0.62s for `A` and 0.37s for `C`. Here the array is large enough that the overhead of making the copies starts to really show. For even larger arrays, the timing difference will be that much larger. Note that the time to compute `C` is close to 100 times larger than in the first case, and that the array `X` is 100 times larger than in the first case. So it is the time to compute `A` that didn't scale nicely with the array size.

So, when deciding how to implement something, try different options, and always time them with *realistic* array sizes.

---

Note for timing:

Always run your timing using functions, and with `timeit`. A loop or function call that takes milliseconds to run cannot be timed correctly with `tic`/`toc`. Only things that take around a second or more to run could be timed the way you did it. But put the code in a function, so that the JIT can be applied. Scripts are JIT'ed in the most recent versions of MATLAB, but not in earlier versions, and therefore `tic`/`toc` should always appear inside a function.

This is what the timing code could look like:

```matlab
X = rand(1e4);
A = methodA(X);
C = methodC(X);
assert(all(all(abs(A-C)<1e-14)))

timeit(@()methodA(X))
timeit(@()methodC(X))

function A = methodA(X)
N = size(X,1);
i=1:2:N-1;
j=1:2:N-1;
A = (X(j,i) + X(j,i+1) + X(j+1,i) + X(j+1,i+1)) / 4;
end

function C = methodC(X)
N = size(X,1);
C = zeros(N/2);
for i=1:N/2
   si = i*2-1;
   for j=1:N/2
      sj = j*2-1;
      C(j,i) = (X(sj,si) + X(sj+1,si) + X(sj,si+1) + X(sj+1,si+1)) / 4;
   end
end
end
```

Comment: MyRestrict is simply the for loop in function form:

`function C = MyRestrictNew(X)
[Ny,Nx]=size(X);
I=1:2:Nx-1;
J=1:2:Ny-1;
C = zeros(Ny/2,Nx/2);
for i=1:length(I)
    for j=1:length(J)
        C(j,i) = (X(J(j),I(i))+X(J(j)+1,I(i))+X(J(j),I(i)+1)+X(J(j)+1,I(i)+1))/4;
    end
end`

Comment: 1e3 is a realistic size for this problem.

Your point about `tic/toc` giving bad results for such small times is well taken. I think that is the reason for the unexpected behavior. `timeit` gives results that make more sense.

And yes, before the JIT compiler, i wouldnt have touched for loops with a ten foot pole!